# HTML scrolling effects

Tags: html, css, fragment-identifier

I'm noticing a lot of sites are recently implementing new types of scrolling effects.  Here's one example:

https://banksimple.com/

When you first start scrolling the initial section stays in place (z-index of 1?) while content scrolls over top of it.  It also uses fragments and dynamically highlights it's navbar depending on what area the user has scrolled to.

I've seen a few sites use similar techniques.  One (which I cannot find the link to) changes the background dynamically.

Is there a common technique used for these types of sites?

Answer (score 0):

The first two sections are using `position:fixed`.

This *fixes* the items to a position on the page.  They don't move, even with scrolling.

The scrolling section uses `position:absolute` with a high `z-index`.

This scrolls fine and because it has a higher `z-index` than the `fixed position` elements, it scrolls over them.

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to do this, but the easiest is to simply make a div, and use the CSS

```
"position:fixed;"
```

property.  This will cause the div to stick exactly where it is, relative to the browser window.

You may also want to set you z-index to a large value so that the div is certain to stay on top of the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

For the menu and header, it's a simple CSS solution using `position: fixed` and `z-index`. Both menu and header has `position: fixed`, while the menu has a large `z-index` value and the main content has a slightly lower one:

```
#menu { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2000; }
#header { position: fixed; top: ??; left: 0; }
#wrapper { z-index: 10; }
```

As for the fragment thing, it's done using JS. [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com) has the same thing, done using jQuery. Perhaps you can decipher [the script](http://w3fools.com/js/script.js). Looks like it hooks to the scroll event of the document, checking if the position if the element is above the position of the viewport, taking action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to combine  CSS + JavaScript let's say (jQuery)

CSS:

`position:fixed` for the top panel.

Use [jQuery offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to detect container position and after you can can apply CSS classes for the "highlights navbar".